# Uncountable Poles of a Laplace Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm trying to prove that a function $F(s)$ of a complex variable resulting from a two-sided Laplace transform can have at most a countable number of poles. I start with a well-known result that a Laplace transform can only give you an analytic (thus holomorphic) function of $s$. Then I reason that if there are uncountably many poles of the Laplace transform, then there must exist some compact subset of the transform's region of convergence that contains infinitely many poles - otherwise, we could have just represented the ROC as a union of a countable number of compact subsets each containing a finite number of poles, which would only give us a countable total number of poles.
That's where I run into problems - how do I prove that it's impossible to have a compact set with an infinite number of poles?

Comment: A pole is by definition isolated, if of order $m$ then $(s-a)^m F(s)$ is analytic and non-zero at $a$. Also did you mean the Laplace transform of an integrable function and $F$ in the open strip of convergence ? For example $s^{-3/2}$ has a branch point so if we include the poles of the analytic continuations of $F$ we need to deal with the different branches (there are countably many).

Comment: @reuns Yes, I meant the strip of absolute convergence. But how would having countably many branches affect the problem?

Comment: It doesn't because there are countably many branches

Comment: @reuns So does it become "obvious" (sorry for swearing) that since every pole must be isolated, it must have some finite (and not infinitesimal) area around it that doesn't contain any other poles?

Comment: $a$ is a pole means that for some $m$, $(s-a)^m F(s)$ is analytic and non-zero at $a$ so there is some disk where it has no other pole (nor zero)

Comment: @reuns and that disk cannot be infinitely small, meaning that we won't be able to pack infinitely many such disks into a finite area?

Comment: The disk can be smaller and smaller when passing to the next poles (eg. $1/\sin(1/z)$). But it implies that there are finitely many poles on each compact, and since your open strip of convergence is covered by a countable sequence of compacts (some closed rectangles) you get that there are at most countably many poles.

Comment: @reuns Thank you!

Comment: Also I feel dumb because the function is analytic on the strip of convergence, it has zero poles. That's why you are indeed considering the analytic continuations (but the argument of covering with countably many compacts still works)